# Set value to date field from data-attribute value in button

Tags: jquery, forms, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap-modal that opens with click on an image and want to populate som input fields in a form.

```
<img role="button" class="" src="/img/edit.svg" alt="" width="40" height="40" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addCourseModal" data-starttime="08.09.2023">
```

In the form I have a date-field that wont populate with the value starttime when the type of field is set to "date". If I change it to text it works, but I need it to be a date-field and have the bootstrap datepicker available.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="addCourseInputStartTime" name="starttime" required>
  </div>
```

The jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
        $('#addCourseModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget); /*Button that triggered the modal*/
            var starttime = button.data('starttime');
            var modal = $(this);
            modal.find('#addCourseInputStartTime').val(starttime);

    });
    });
        
});
</script>
```

I understand that I probably need to do something different to populate the date-field, but I cant find anything about it unfortunatly.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed I got a message in the console:

The specified value "03.02.2023" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

So when I change the format in the attribute, it works fine.